# Why changing DNS won't bypass the internet censorship

Tags: internet, bypass

[Reddit](http://reddit.com) is blocked by my ISP. :(

I have tried changing my DNS Servers to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, both in my computer (Windows) and my Router (TP-Link Router).

Some say that it will bypass the internet censorship, but why it won't work this time ?

I'm a newbie and don't have much knowledge on internet protocols

Comment: Even though you send the reddit.com request to a different DNS server, the information still has to come back through your ISP's filtering server.

Comment: @AnDorfer So it means that accessing reddit.com by its IP Address won't bypass the filtering either?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things that will let you access reddit:

1. [VPN](http://freevpn.me) - gives you a different IP when requesting information from reddit
2. [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) - gives you a different IP when requesting information from reddit

A DNS change will only change where you are going to ask for information, not your identity.

Accessing reddit.com by entering it's IP in the browser does what would happen by default by typing reddit.com into the browser. It doesn't change who is asking for information.

In the event that a nameserver is down, and reddit.com does not resolve to an IP, entering the IP manually is the only way to access reddit.com

Answer (score 0):

If the ISP doesn't really block the website, which means just removing host name from its `DNS` server, changing `DNS` server will resolve this issue. Otherwise this method won't work. (Please refer [How To Bypass Facebook and Other Internet Censorship In Vietnam](https://toomanyadapters.com/bypass-facebook-internet-censorship-vietnam/)).